# SMTP IIS Relay - attachments are encoded in email body

Tags: smtp, email-server, iis-7.5

Server 2008 R2, MS IIS build 7.5 being used as an outgoing SMTP relay only.  Session/message limits and attachment limits set to 500 MB per attachment and session.  Attachment is between 10-20 KB.

When sending out mass e-mails via our `GoldMine CRM software`, the attachment comes through in the body of the text as base64 encoding.  If I send it out via Outlook it works fine.  Sending the e-mail with attachment via `GoldMine` to an individual comes through just fine.  It's only when sending to multiple recipients.  This also includes `HTML` based e-mails.  The HTML will come through as plain text and not parsed.

If I change the outgoing SMTP to use our ISP's server which is also an IIS 7.5 relay (relay.somedomain.com -- 66.110.x.x) it goes through with success.

xmail*.myhosting.com is the 3rd party e-mail hosting provider we use to receive our e-mail.  We stopped using them as an outgoing host because we were constantly being black listed via RBL's.

**Here is the e-mail server log:**

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-05-17 13:12:32
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-computername s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-query sc-status sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken cs-version cs-host cs(User-Agent) 
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 EHLO +MAILSVR01.localdomain.com 250 0 231 36 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 MAIL +FROM:<me@ourdomain.com> 250 0 46 33 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 RCPT +TO:<email1@ourdomain.com> 250 0 35 32 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 RCPT +TO:<email2@ourdomain.com> 250 0 33 30 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 RCPT +TO:<email3@ourdomain.com> 250 0 32 29 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 RCPT +TO:<email4@ourdomain.com> 250 0 38 35 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 RCPT +TO:<email5@ourdomain.com> 250 0 37 34 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 RCPT +TO:<email6@ourdomain.com> 250 0 34 31 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 DATA +<SjQ5TkVLTShMNzFHJD5QNTk3ODk5NzEy@MAILSVR01> 250 0 130 43284 15 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 220+relay.COC.com+Microsoft+ESMTP+MAIL+Service,+Version:+7.5.7600.16385+ready+at++Tue,+17+May+2016+09:12:31+-0400+ 0 0 114 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 EHLO MAILSVR01.localdomain.com 0 0 4 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 250-relay.somedomain.com+Hello+[66.110.xx.xxx] 0 0 39 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 MAIL FROM:<sender1@ourdomain.com>+SIZE=43574 0 0 4 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 250+2.1.0+sender1@ourdomain.com....Sender+OK 0 0 44 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 RCPT TO:<email1@ourdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 RCPT TO:<email2@ourdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 RCPT TO:<email3@ourdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 RCPT TO:<email4@ourdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 RCPT TO:<email5@ourdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 RCPT TO:<email6@ourdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 250+2.1.5+email1@ourdomain.com+ 0 0 33 0 0 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 250+2.1.5+email2@ourdomain.com+ 0 0 31 0 16 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 250+2.1.5+email3@ourdomain.com+ 0 0 35 0 16 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 250+2.1.5+email4@ourdomain.com+ 0 0 31 0 16 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 BDAT 43574+LAST 0 0 4 0 16 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 250+2.6.0+<RELAYbnGjke2bgzMnJt00001ab6@relay.somedomain.com>+Queued+mail+for+delivery 0 0 78 0 344 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 QUIT - 0 0 4 0 344 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionResponse MAILSVR01 - 25 - 221+2.0.0+relay.somedomain.com+Service+closing+transmission+channel 0 0 60 0 344 SMTP - -
2016-05-17 13:12:34 192.168.x.x MAILSVR01.localdomain.com MAILSVR01 192.168.4.15 0 QUIT MAILSVR01.localdomain.com 240 1794 79 4 0 SMTP - -
```

**This is how the e-mail is received with headers:**

```
Return-Path: <myemail@ourdomain.com>
Delivered-To: myemail@ourdomain.com
Received: (qmail 26071 invoked from network); 17 May 2016 12:33:54 -0000
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on xsa04.softcom.biz
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-DCC: : xsa04 1323; Body=1 Fuz1=1
X-Spam-Pyzor: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-0.1 hits=-0.1 required=5.0 tests=AWL,BAYES_00,
    MISSING_HEADERS,RDNS_NONE,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=no version=3.3.1
Received: from unknown (HELO relay.somedomain.com) ([66.110.xx.xx])
          (envelope-sender <myemail@ourdomain.com>)
          by xmail04.myhosting.com (qmail-ldap-1.03) with SMTP
          for <email1@ourdomain.com>; 17 May 2016 12:33:48 -0000
Received: from MAILSVR01.localdomain.com  ([66.110.xx.xx]) by relay.somedomain.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7600.16385);
     Tue, 17 May 2016 08:30:14 -0400
Received: from MAILSVR01.localdomain.com  ([192.168.x.xx]) by MAILSVR01.localdomain.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.17514);
     Tue, 17 May 2016 08:30:15 -0400
Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 08:30:15 -0400
From: Travis <myemail@ourdomain.com>
Subject: Test Day 2 #1
Bcc:
Return-Path: myemail@ourdomain.com
Message-ID: <RELAYz2hW3BdeUJt3qL00001ab4@relay.somedomain.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 17 May 2016 12:30:14.0665 (UTC) FILETIME=[DCECC790:01D1B037]

To:  ---redacted--
Message-ID: <SjQ5S09PSyFKWDEgJD5QNTk1MzYyNTEy@MAILSVR01>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Organization: Company Name
X-Mailer: GoldMine [2014.1.0.489]
X-GM-Attachments-Sync-Time: 20160517083014
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="nqp=nb64=()17phzZSPf"
Return-Path: myemail@ourdomain.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 17 May 2016 12:30:15.0874 (UTC) FILETIME=[DDA54220:01D1B037]

--nqp=nb64=()17phzZSPf
Content-Type: text/plain

Test day 2


--nqp=nb64=()17phzZSPf
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="image9.jpeg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image9.jpeg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

/9j/4Q/+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACwEPAAIAAAAGAAAAkgEQAAIAAAAJAAAAmAESAAMAAAAB
AAYAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAogEbAAUAAAABAAAAqgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAGAAAAsgEy
-----removed fluff to cut down for Server Fault character limit----
AKGhrCvfip8DkRkktNfYf9d7fj6/uqwm+K/wSBaSHT9dcdCDcwdPUYhqPrstbN/cy3RXl+B/
/9l=

--nqp=nb64=()17phzZSPf--
```

Headers for a successful e-mail attachment through our ISP's SMTP.

```
Subject:Test Day 2 #2
            Date:Tuesday, May 17, 2016 8:43 am
            From:Travis <myemail@ourdomain.com>
            To:<redcated recipients>
            Org:Western Plastics
            X-Mailer:GoldMine [2014.1.0.489]
            MIME Version:1.0
            MIME Type:multipart/mixed; boundary="nqp=nb64=()J6Ske6A0R"
            Message-id:<SjQ5TEtDMSA5QF9JJD5QNTk2MTgyODU4@MAILSVR1>
            Return-Path:<myemail@ourdomain.com>
            Delivered-To:myemail@ourdomain.com
            Received:(qmail 1683 invoked from network); 17 May 2016 12:47:28 
            -0000
            X-Spam-Checker-Version:SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on 
            xsa09.softcom.biz
            X-Spam-DCC:: xsa09 1323; Body=1 Fuz1=1
            X-Spam-Status:No, score=0.5 hits=0.5 required=5.0 
            tests=AWL,BAYES_50, RDNS_NONE,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=no 
            version=3.3.1
            Received:from unknown (HELO relay.COC.com) ([66.110.220.12])         
             (envelope-sender <myemail@ourdomain.com>)          by 
            xmail08.myhosting.com (qmail-ldap-1.03) with SMTP          for 
            <email1@ourdomain.com>; 17 May 2016 12:47:24 -0000
            Received:from MAILSVR1.localdomain.com ([66.110.xx.xx]) by 
            relay.somedomain.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7600.16385);  Tue, 17 May 
            2016 08:43:54 -0400
            Return-Path:myemail@ourdomain.com
            X-OriginalArrivalTime:17 May 2016 12:43:54.0806 (UTC) 
            FILETIME=[C5C45D60:01D1B039]

            Attachments:\\192.168.x.x\MailBox\Attach\TRAVIS\image7.jpeg




Test Email 2
```

Comment: "attachment comes through in the body of the text as base64 encoding" If I'm not mistaken, this is actually the only way attachments can be sent in an e-mail, and this process will happen at some stage of the e-mail transmission. It seems like sending the e-mail in different ways is changing *when* the attachment is encoded, but not *whether* it is encoded. Your question doesn't make it clear what the actual problem is. What goes wrong with the Goldmine CRM e-mails?

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong with the sending of GoldMine vs Outlook e-mails.  The attachment is coming through as text in the body of the e-mail instead of as an actual attachment.  I can't see any real difference in the process via logs or headers which is why I posted both.  Additionally if I don't use our in house SMTP relay, it goes through fine.

Comment: Ah, so when the recipient of the GoldMine e-mails opens the e-mail, they don't see an attachment at all, instead they see the encoded text? If that's so, then perhaps reaching out to GoldMine support and seeing if they can help you with GoldMine configuration regarding attachments?

Comment: I have already reached out to GoldMine.  They have not seen this issue and are looking into it.  However, I don't think it's completely the fault of GoldMine as it works fine with our ISP's IIS outgoing SMTP relay.  I believe it has to be some configuration I'm missing on our inhouse relay that I can't find.

Comment: We have determined that it is not a GoldMine issue but an issue with the outgoing SMTP server.  There must be a setting I'm missing that's causing this.

Comment: @ToddWilcox got it fixed.  Thanks for the help.  Posted answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out after a lot of scrutinizing log files.

The e-mail client was sending `DATA` but the internal SMTP server was sending it out to the smart host via `BDAT` and evidently this is a potential DDoS issue and I guess somewhere along the way it was not allowing it to process properly.  It's possible that our `SonicWall` firewall was screwing with it some how also.

**Offending Line:**

`2016-05-17 13:12:32 66.110.xx.xxx OutboundConnectionCommand MAILSVR01 - 25 BDAT 43574+LAST 0 0 4 0 16 SMTP - -`

So the solution was to disable BDAT, BINARYMIME and CHUNKING on the local SMTP Server.

**Credit/Source Link**:

https://adaptivethinking.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/smtp-esmtp-and-the-bdat-baddie/

https://joekiller.com/2007/09/19/bdat-causing-smtp-service-to-drop-email/

---

**In case the link is no longer available here are the steps they outlined.**

---

Telnet to the mail host and issue the `ehlo` command.  Check the verbs the server returns.  It should have `BINARYMIME` and `CHUNKING` listed.  After these steps you will not have these.

---

**Verify `BINARYMIME` and `CHUNKING` are turned on.**:
`telnet localhost 25`

`Type ehlo`

```
220 MAILSVR Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 7.5.76
01.17514 ready at  Tue, 14 Mar 2017 12:18:50 -0400
ehlo
250-MAILSVR Hello [168.1.1.1]
250-TURN
250-SIZE 51200000
250-ETRN
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-8bitmime
250-VRFY
250-TLS
250-STARTTLS
250 OK
```

---

**Install [IIS6.0 Resource Kit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671)**

Open `IIS Metabase Explorer`

Navigate to `LM\SmtpSvc\1`

Look for `SmtpInboundCommandSupportOptions`

Here the default value was `7697601`.  I knew that I wanted to disable the BINARYMIME and CHUNKING verbs so using the [table here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257569/) I subtracted `2097152` (BINARYMIME) and `1048576` (CHUNKING) from `7697601`:

`7697601 - (2097152 + 1048576) = 4551873`

Set the `SmtpInboundCommandSupportOptions` value to `4551873`

---

**Disable BDAT**

Navigate to `LM\SmtpSvc`

Change value of `SmtpOutboundCommandSupportOptions` from `7` to `5`

Close the `IIS Metabase Explorer` and restarted the `IIS Admin Service` (which in turn restarts the `Simple Mail Transfer Protocol` (SMTP) service).

Repeat the steps to connect to the server via `telnet` and verify they have been removed.  If they have not make sure you are in the `\1` subdirectory when you make the changes.

Comment: Wow. That's pretty subtle. Nice catch!

Comment: how do you disable BDAT on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: @Cerveser I'm assuming it's the same procedures since I think 2012 uses IIS 6 also.

Comment: Yes, it worked! I only needed the IIS Metabase Explorer to change the values, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to the excellent answer from @Travis.

In my situation I am running the IIS6 SMTP server to relay mail to an IBM Domino server.

We wanted to allow multiple attachments in an email, but found that more than one attachment caused IIS to invoke `BDAT` when relaying, which the Domino server didn't support and would silently discard the entire email.

I changed `SmtpOutboundCommandSupportOptions` as suggested and restarted the `IIS Admin Service`.

Oddly, then we could pass up to four attachments but on the fifth attachment it would revert to invoking `BDAT`.

Per [this Peer Wisdom blog post](http://www.peerwisdom.org/2013/03/19/iis-smtp-server-smtpoutboundcommandsupportoptions-bug/), the value for `SmtpInboundCommandSupportOptions`and `SmtpOutboundCommandSupportOptions` should actually follow the same pattern.

Setting `SmtpOutboundCommandSupportOptions` to `4551873` solved the problem for me.